# 401 (Unauthorized) in Google Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

When I Get the document list from SharePoint site I get this error "401 (Unauthorized)" only in Google Chrome, but in IE it works. This is my code

```
function GetListItems() {
var siteURL = "http://localhost:8032/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Data%20Do')/File";
            return $.ajax({
                url: siteURL,
                async: false,
                method: "GET",

                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                }
            });
        }
```

I get this two error in Google Chrome:

> OPTIONS "http:......" 401 (Unauthorized)

and

> jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8032/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Data%20Do')/Files. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8032' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Close chrome and restart with the --disable-web-security Mode and then try if it opens up correctly

Comment: Question:
Have you tried it in an incognito Chrome window?
I have several sites that don't work in regular Chrome windows but work in incognito windows.

Comment: Localhost? What type of app are you developing?  If this is a provider-hosted app, you need to use OAUTH, cookies or an NTLM header.  If this is sharepoint-hosted, then you need the request digest.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the Negotiate provider in Authentication in IIS.

After adding Negotiate, make an IIS  reset . This will work .

Comment: The correct way to enable Kerberos for SharePoint is described here: https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/10/enabling-kerberos-sharepoint/. You shouldn't mess around with Authentication-settings directly in IIS.